# Run out on wide ball

Tags: rules, cricket

If any batsman or non-striker batsman gets run out on a wide ball, will that ball be counted as a legal delivery, or still be called a wide with extra run ?

Answer (score 8):

A wide is always a wide, and always gives one run to the batting team. It doesn't matter if the batsman was out from the ball, whether that be run out, stumped or any of the other ways a batsman can be out from a wide.

This is explicitly covered in (what was in 2015) [Law 25.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20150610211441/https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-25-wide-ball/):

> 5. Penalty for a Wide
>
> A penalty of one run shall be awarded instantly on the call of Wide ball. [...] this penalty shall stand even if a batsman is dismissed, and shall be in addition to any other runs scored, any boundary allowance and any other runs awarded for penalties.

As of 2023, this is now [Law 22.6](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/wide-ball) with essentially the same wording.